# Why does my image gallery not work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I built an image gallery for my website, and when I view it in the browser it works, but on the mobile it does not work. Here is a  PC version screenshot [PC screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtATo.png), and here is the mobile screenshot [Mobile screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u46T4.jpg). I tried adding a media queries, but it does not work. [Site link](https://dazzling-feynman-4ac502.netlify.com)

html:

```
 <div class="carousel-container">
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-right" id="nextBtn"></i>
        <i class="fas fa-arrow-left" id="prevBtn"></i>
        <div class="carousel-slide" >
          <img src="./Page3/sajla.jpg" id='lastClone' alt="" >
          <img src="./Page3/bucice.jpg" alt="">
          <img src="./Page3/lat.jpg" alt="">
          <img src="./Page3/row sprava.jpg" alt="">
          <img src="./Page3/sajla.jpg" alt="">
          <img src="./Page3/bucice.jpg" id="firstClone" alt="">
        </div>
```

css:

```
.carousel-container{
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
   border: 5rem solid #75BF4F;
   border-radius: 3rem;
  position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-slide{
    display: flex;
    height: 80rem;
    width: 100%;


}
.carousel-slide img{
    width: 100%;

}
#prevBtn{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10rem;
    width: 10rem;
    border-radius: 20rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 5%;
    font-size: 6rem;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #C4C4C4;
}
#nextBtn{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10rem;
    width: 10rem;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 20rem;
    background-color: #C4C4C4;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
    right: 5%;
    font-size: 6rem;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

javascipt:

```
const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');
const prevBtn  = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn  = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');

let counter = 1;
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    if(counter >= carouselImages.length - 1)return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter++;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

});
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    if(counter <= 0)return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter--;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

});

carouselSlide.addEventListener('transitionend',()=>{
console.log(carouselImages[0])
if(carouselImages[counter].id === 'lastClone'){
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
    counter = carouselImages.length - 2;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

}
});
carouselSlide.addEventListener('transitionend',()=>{
    console.log(carouselImages[0])
    if(carouselImages[counter].id === 'firstClone'){
        carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
        counter = carouselImages.length - counter;
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

    }
    });
```

Comment: I don't really see the problem? Could you go more in-depth on what you are experiencing vs what you want to happen

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=16eRD-n_uzBvATy8x61BFqU0hPpAZHzVx https://drive.google.com/open?id=11DBLdO7lJqlhUEOX9xytyfmuhPre_CZV These are links to the videos viewing from the PC when it works and from phone when it does not

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: Please give a specific OS, browser, and version where it doesn't work. "Mobile" is way too generic.

Comment: Today i tried it on mobile and it worked  once, than next time it does not. I tried it on Huawei Mate 10 pro, Huawei P20 pro,Samsung Galaxy A70 and for all of them it was same.Lets say one of 10 times i open site it works ,every other time it does not. It tried it on google chrome-mobile version  and on samsung stock browser.

Comment: What version number of Chrome?

Comment: Chrome Version 79.0.3945.117  and Chrome Version Version 79.0.3945.116 on my phone

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is quite easy to solve. Some browsers still doesn't support the newest ECMA syntax. Try replacing all `const` and `let` to `var` and all your arrow functions to regular ones.

I modified your code to make it possibly work on mobile. Try it:

```
var carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');
var carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel-slide img');
var prevBtn  = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
var nextBtn  = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');

var counter = 1;
var size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;

carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(counter >= carouselImages.length - 1) return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter++;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

});
prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(counter <= 0) return;
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
    counter--;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

});

carouselSlide.addEventListener('transitionend',function() {
console.log(carouselImages[0])
if(carouselImages[counter].id === 'lastClone'){
    carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
    counter = carouselImages.length - 2;
    carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

}
});
carouselSlide.addEventListener('transitionend', function() {
    console.log(carouselImages[0])
    if(carouselImages[counter].id === 'firstClone'){
        carouselSlide.style.transition = "none";
        counter = carouselImages.length - counter;
        carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.I tried replacing my code with provided one and it still does not work.